# ElasticSearch Query Not Working on Some Fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

**I am creating a search in my webapp with the following search parameters. This query is not working on some fields like MaxScore, Experience ,Salary. When I put the same query separately in postman it is working.Please go through my piece of code and let me know where I went wrong as this is my first query in elastic so there is a lot of scope in improvement.
Also share your views if there is better way of doing this in elastic**

Below is my JAVA code and query generated for my search parameters but this is not working when searching for individual parameters like MaxScore, Experience ,Salary.
**In what way I have to create the mappings and analyser to make my code give desired results? In range queries, hits are not as per the query**

>

```
 {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "term" : {
        "sectionalscores.examTitleId" : 3
      }
    },
    "should" : [ {
      "range" : {
        "userdata.expectedSalary" : {
          "from" : 500000.0,
          "to" : 1000000.0,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "userdata.experienceInYears" : {
          "from" : 0,
          "to" : 1,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "userdata.higestQualPercentCgpa" : {
          "from" : 2014,
          "to" : 100.0,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "userdata.higestQualPassingYear" : {
          "from" : 2014,
          "to" : 2100,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "examscores.scorePercent" : {
          "from" : 70.0,
          "to" : 100,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "match" : {
        "userdata.keySkills" : {
          "query" : "Tomcat Jboss",
          "type" : "phrase"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "userdata.xPercentageCgpa" : {
          "from" : 80.0,
          "to" : 100,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "userdata.xIIPercentageCgpa" : {
          "from" : 90.0,
          "to" : 100,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "range" : {
        "sectionalscores.scorePercent" : {
          "from" : 70.0,
          "to" : 100,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

**Here is the JAVA code**

```
public List<String> getCandidatesbySearchParameters(RecruiterSearchParameters params) throws UnknownHostException {

        ElasticSearch elastic = ElasticSearch.Factory.getInstance();
        String examTakenFrom= "now-"+params.getDaysForlastExamTaken()+"d";
        elastic.addIndexes("km-test");
        elastic.addTypes("km-user");
        BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        if (params.getCountry() != null && !params.getCountry().isEmpty())
            query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("userdata.country", params.getCountry()));

        if (params.getExpectedSalaryMax() > 0 && params.getExpectedSalaryMin() > 0 && params.getExpectedSalaryMax()> params.getExpectedSalaryMin())
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("userdata.expectedSalary").lte(params.getExpectedSalaryMax()).gte(params.getExpectedSalaryMin()));

        if (params.getExperienceMax() > 0 && params.getExperienceMin() >= 0 && params.getExperienceMax() > params.getExperienceMin())
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("userdata.experienceInYears").lte(params.getExperienceMax()).gte(params.getExperienceMin()));

        if (params.getGender() != null && !params.getGender().isEmpty())
            query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("userdata.gender", params.getGender()));

        if (params.getHighestDegreePercent() > 0)
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("userdata.higestQualPercentCgpa").gte(params.getHighestQualPassingYear()).lte(100.0));

        if (params.getHighestQualPassingYear() > 0)
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("userdata.higestQualPassingYear").gte(params.getHighestQualPassingYear()).lte(2100));

        if (params.geMaxScore() > 0)
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("examscores.scorePercent").gte(params.getMaxScore()).lte(100));

        if (params.getKeySkills() != null && !params.getKeySkills().isEmpty())
            //query.should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("userdata.keySkills", params.getKeySkills().get(0),params.getKeySkills().get(1),params.getKeySkills().get(2)));
        query.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("userdata.keySkills","Tomcat Jboss"));

        if (params.getDaysForlastExamTaken() > 0)
            query.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("examscores.examDate").from(examTakenFrom).to("now"));      

        if (params.getLocation() != null && !params.getLocation().isEmpty())
            query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("userdata.currentlocation", params.getLocation()));

        if (params.getPercentageX() > 0)
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("userdata.xPercentageCgpa").gte(params.getPercentageX()).lte(100));

        if (params.getPercentageXII() > 0)
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("userdata.xIIPercentageCgpa").gte(params.getPercentageXII()).lte(100));

        if (params.getExamtitleId() > 0)
            query.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("sectionalscores.examTitleId", params.getExamtitleId()));

        if (params.getSectionalScore() > 0)
            query.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("sectionalscores.scorePercent").gte(params.getSectionalScore()).lte(100));

        if (params.getVideoInterview() == true)
            query.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("userdata.videoIntroUrl"));

        //Make a list of Objects with fields title id and sectional score percentage
        for(Integer titleId : params.getSectionalScoresMap().keySet()){
            query.must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("sectionalscores", QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("sectionalscores.examTitleId",titleId ))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("sectionalscores.scorePercent").gte(params.getSectionalScoresMap().get(titleId)).lte(100))));
        }
          elastic.addQuery(query);
        elastic.setPage(1);
          elastic.setSize(60); 
          SearchResponse sr = elastic.execute(); 
          SearchHit[] results =  sr.getHits().hits(); List<String> sourceAsString = new
          ArrayList<String>(); for(SearchHit hit : results){
          sourceAsString.add(hit.getSourceAsString()); }

        return sourceAsString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also share the working query you send in Postman?

Comment: I am not using postman but i can send the query generated after running this code.

Comment: yes, please share it

Comment: http://localhost:9200/km-test/km-user/_search?q=experienceInYears=1

Comment: Should be `localhost:9200/km-test/km-user/_search?q=userdata.experienceInYears:1`

Comment: it is working in postman , I mean results are coming but the query generated by the code is complex and I cannot add this in "GET" request body using postman. i would have attached the query but it has crossed the characters limit in comment.

Comment: You can send the generated query from Postman using POST and copying the query in the body payload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120200/discussion-between-lamba-and-val).

Comment: Since this is your first query in ES, I suggest you start with **much** simpler  queries and learn the query DSL step-by-step instead of trying a big-bang query ;-)

Comment: okay Val, sure thing  :-)

Comment: You may use kibana and marvel plugin to query es and learn better. Cheers :)